# web scraping with HTTPS, forms authentication, viewestate and using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, https, web-scraping, forms-authentication, screen-scraping

I wanted to do a web scraping on the site that built with HTTPS, forms authentication, viewstates

I want to scrape secured pages those are accessible after login. I found lots of example on google but those are not working. Please anyone can help or suggest some good example then it would be good.

How is this possible with asp.net?

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds a little sketchy. Do you have valid credentials for the sites you want to scrape? Do their terms of service allow you to scrape *legally*?

Comment: @Cory Yes I have both. Can you help to achieve this?

Comment: @Cory can you please help me for this issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the knowledge or experience to provide any concrete examples on how to do this. Since this question isn't getting much attention, I would suggest deleting it, and re-asking it showing exactly what you've tried -- show the examples you found "on google" and why they don't work.